# App to draw bit/byte based messages from plain text description

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, plain-text, diagram, documentation-generator

I *think* I saw a similar question here a few years back, just just can't find it.

I would like to draw descriptions of messages like this:

[image]

From a plain-text input file which describes them.

Maybe something like:

- start byte
- start bit
- length
- text

Preferably cross-platform, but I will settle for Windows.

Comment: Any particular requirements for the output (e.g. file format, image size, resolution/DPI, etc.)?

Comment: No, I will accept anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept pseudo-graphic lines in text, then [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) is a solution. It has plugin **Draw Lines** (install from Plugins/ Addon Manager) to draw such lines/frames in plain text. Here is example of frames:

```
┌───┬─────────────────────────┐
│ 0 │     IE identifier       │
├───┴─────────────────────────┤
│    Length of IE             │
├─────────────────────────────┤
│          Data               │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

Paint such lines by Shift+arrows while plugin is activated. Toggle single/double lines by F9.

Comment: That looks god enough. Do you have a URL for the plug in?

Comment: Folder: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cudatext/files/addons/plugins/